# How To Group Json Objects In Each Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

Hello I am from a php background and trying to group some JSON data via Javascript/JQuery. I want to group the data by cropping the SKU and grouping the records together which I have successfully done however I can not get the data into the 'children' section it seems to only loop the first record. The children section should ideally have all the data from the JSON file but group them by the parent SKU.

I have tried the following:

```js
var items = [
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [
      {
        label: "Size",
        value: "7.5",
        option_id: 190,
        option_value: 106
      }
    ],
    qty: 3,
    item_id: "300",
    product_id: "88105",
    product_name: "MENS SHOE TUDOR BLACK",
    product_sku: "M1S-TUD02-AVEL-79-7.5",
  },
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [
      {
        label: "Size",
        value: "11",
        option_id: 190,
        option_value: 99
      }
    ],
    qty: 3,
    item_id: "298",
    product_id: "88105",
    product_name: "MENS SHOE TUDOR BLACK",
    product_sku: "M1S-TUD02-AVEL-79-11",
  },
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [
      {
        label: "Size",
        value: "M",
        option_id: 190,
        option_value: 66
      }
    ],
    qty: 1,
    item_id: "111",
    product_id: "99945",
    product_name: "WOMENS SWEATER",
    product_sku: "W1R-613K-A10400-96-M",
  },
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [
      {
        label: "Size",
        value: "L",
        option_id: 190,
        option_value: 12
      }
    ],
    qty: 20,
    item_id: "278",
    product_id: "99945",
    product_name: "WOMENS SWEATER",
    product_sku: "W1R-613K-A10400-96-L",
  },
];

var groupedItems = {};
$.each(items, function(key, item) {
  if (item.product_type === "configurable") {
    var sku = item.product_sku,
      parentSku = sku.replace(sku.substring(sku.lastIndexOf("-")), "");

    if (sku.indexOf(parentSku) >= 0) {
      groupedItems[parentSku] = {
        product_sku: parentSku,
        product_name: item.product_name,
        product_type: item.product_type,
        children: [item]
      };
    }
  }
});
console.log(groupedItems);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be more than welcomed. I want an array which will group the data in their respective groups and have some information i.e name, parent sku etc from the first record then the children section having all of the information of the items but obviously in their respective groups. Hope it makes sense! Thanks once again!

Comment: Can you provide an example of expected output? In the question please

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
items.forEach(x => {
  let k=x.product_sku.replace(/-[^-]*?$/,'');
  let g=groupedItems[k]||[];
  g.push(x);
  groupedItems[k]=g;
})
```

```js
var items = [
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [
      {
        label: "Size",
        value: "7.5",
        option_id: 190,
        option_value: 106
      }
    ],
    qty: 3,
    item_id: "300",
    product_id: "88105",
    product_name: "MENS SHOE TUDOR BLACK",
    product_sku: "M1S-TUD02-AVEL-79-7.5",
  },
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [
      {
        label: "Size",
        value: "11",
        option_id: 190,
        option_value: 99
      }
    ],
    qty: 3,
    item_id: "298",
    product_id: "88105",
    product_name: "MENS SHOE TUDOR BLACK",
    product_sku: "M1S-TUD02-AVEL-79-11",
  },
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [
      {
        label: "Size",
        value: "M",
        option_id: 190,
        option_value: 66
      }
    ],
    qty: 1,
    item_id: "111",
    product_id: "99945",
    product_name: "WOMENS SWEATER",
    product_sku: "W1R-613K-A10400-96-M",
  },
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [
      {
        label: "Size",
        value: "L",
        option_id: 190,
        option_value: 12
      }
    ],
    qty: 20,
    item_id: "278",
    product_id: "99945",
    product_name: "WOMENS SWEATER",
    product_sku: "W1R-613K-A10400-96-L",
  },
];

var groupedItems = {};

items.forEach(x => {
  let k=x.product_sku.replace(/-[^-]*?$/,'');
  let g=groupedItems[k]||[];
  g.push(x);
  groupedItems[k]=g;
})
  
console.log(groupedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to group by the `product-sku`

```js
var items = [{
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [{
      label: "Size",
      value: "7.5",
      option_id: 190,
      option_value: 106
    }],
    qty: 3,
    item_id: "300",
    product_id: "88105",
    product_name: "MENS SHOE TUDOR BLACK",
    product_sku: "M1S-TUD02-AVEL-79-7.5",
  },
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [{
      label: "Size",
      value: "11",
      option_id: 190,
      option_value: 99
    }],
    qty: 3,
    item_id: "298",
    product_id: "88105",
    product_name: "MENS SHOE TUDOR BLACK",
    product_sku: "M1S-TUD02-AVEL-79-11",
  },
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [{
      label: "Size",
      value: "M",
      option_id: 190,
      option_value: 66
    }],
    qty: 1,
    item_id: "111",
    product_id: "99945",
    product_name: "WOMENS SWEATER",
    product_sku: "W1R-613K-A10400-96-M",
  },
  {
    product_type: "configurable",
    options: [{
      label: "Size",
      value: "L",
      option_id: 190,
      option_value: 12
    }],
    qty: 20,
    item_id: "278",
    product_id: "99945",
    product_name: "WOMENS SWEATER",
    product_sku: "W1R-613K-A10400-96-L",
  },
];

var groupedItems = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.product_type === "configurable") {
    var sku = item.product_sku;
    var parentSku = sku.replace(sku.substring(sku.lastIndexOf("-")), "");
  
    if (sku.indexOf(parentSku) >= 0) {
      if (!!acc[parentSku]) {
        let children = acc[parentSku].children;
        acc[parentSku].children = [...children, { ...item
        }];
      } else {
        acc[parentSku] = {
          product_sku: parentSku,
          product_name: item.product_name,
          product_type: item.product_type,
          children: [item]
        };
      }
    }
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(groupedItems);
```

Comment: Please open the developer tools and check the console